# What are the different OTA dlls used for

Tags: hp-quality-center, scriptom

I am looking to connect ALM and soapUI and while i was looking for the OTA dll i found a bunch of other libraries with the word OTA in their name.

```
interop.OTAClient
interop.OTAClient.dll
interop.OTAReport.DLL
OTAClient.Api.dll
OTAClient.Core.dll
OTAClient.dll
OTAClient.Entities.dll
OTAClientLib.dll
OtaReport.dll
OTAWrapperLib.dll
OTAXml.dll
QCClient.StandardExtension.OTA.dll
```

I am wondering if someone out there knows what these dlls are for?

Answer (score 0):

Most of these dlls are part of the ALM Client. 
The ones you really need to be able to user OTA api are

OTACLIENT.DLL
WebClient.dll

Both need to be registered.

Comment: I didn't know i needed the WebClient.dll too. However this doesn't answer my question, what are all these OTA dlls used for? Maybe i should add them to eclipse and see what methods they expose.